# Swift Send Push Notification from user to user Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app using Swift and Firebase. When the user presses a button the app will upload some data to the real time database and send another user a Push Notification. Is possible by making the other user subscribe to the changes in the realtime database or will this not check for changes when the app is not in the foreground?

Should I upload the data then use Cloud Messaging to alert the user of the new data?

Thank you

Comment: Hey, Tom. I am having the same issue right now with User to User push notifications. Did you manage to do it in your app and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FCM for this use case. Having the app listen for changes to the database while in the background is not good for device battery, so you should have your application server listen to the database for changes then send appropriate FCM messages to let the client app know that there are changes.

Comment: Is the App Server something I can set up inside Firebase or should I be using a different service for this? Thank you.

Comment: You would have to use a diff service, eg: Google compute engine

Comment: Okay great. Do you know were I could find any tutorials to help with this or even if there are any? Thank you

Comment: Tom, did you get anywhere with this in the last month? Wondering what the best provider is for "user to user" push. Got Firebase all setup but this is only for blanket notifications that I wish to throw out there in the console...